# Is it possible to return or somehow access the data from "courses" from this method?

Tags: java, methods, return

I'm working on my first programming assignment for Java and I had another question. I put a Course[] inside of Student[] but now seem to be encountering a NullPointerException error and I can't figure out why.

```
public Student[] analyzeData() {
    Scanner inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Programming Assignment 1 Data.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Programming Assignment 1 Data.txt could not be found or opened.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int numberOfStudents = inputStream.nextInt();
    int tuitionPerHour = inputStream.nextInt();

    Student[] students = new Student[numberOfStudents];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        String firstName = inputStream.next();
        String lastName = inputStream.next();
        int studentID = inputStream.nextInt();
        String isTuitionPaid = inputStream.next();
        int numberOfCourses = inputStream.nextInt();


        Course[] courses = new Course[numberOfCourses];
        for (i = 0; i < numberOfCourses; i++) {
            String courseName = inputStream.next();
            String courseNumber = inputStream.next();
            int creditHours = inputStream.nextInt();
            String grade = inputStream.next();
            Course currentCourse = new Course(courseName, courseNumber, creditHours, grade);
            courses[i] = currentCourse;
        }
        Student currentStudent = new Student(firstName, lastName, studentID, isTuitionPaid, numberOfCourses, courses);
        students[i] = currentStudent;
    }
    return students;
}
```

The formatting for the input file is:

```
3 345
Lisa Miller 890238 Y 2 
Mathematics MTH345 4 A
Physics PHY357 3 B


Bill Wilton 798324 N 2
English ENG378 3 B
Philosophy PHL534 3 A
```

Where courses has information about the courses, and students has information about the students.

Comment: first of all, if you are using eclipse (which i highly recommend) Try ctrl+shift+f, it is auto format and is nice for making you code easier to read until you get into the habit of using good formating on your own.

Comment: Could you specify where the `NullPointerException` is occurring?  Although, I could wager a guess that all of the code that relates to your Scanner object should be encapsulated inside of your `try...catch` block, since `inputStream` is null if the file isn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an array (or better yet, ArrayList or a Map) to `Student` that contains the classes the student is taking.

With what you're doing, how are you determining which classes go with which students?

Try adding the following instance variable

```
  private List<Course> courses;
```

to `Student`, then implement the following methods to add to the List or return the whole thing.

```
  void addCourse(Course c) { /*code here*/ };
  List getCourses() {/* code here */} ;
```

And reading files can be a real pain, what you have is ok, at least for now.  Your loop where `Course` is instantiated would include a call `student.addCourse(course)`. Then you'll be golden.

Be advised this is a high level overview so there could be some learnage in here for you.  Just post back and we'll help.

Comment: The professor requested that we not use lists, and I don't actually know how to make one, unfortunately.
My plan was only to just read all of the classes after each student and use that as a way to assign them to students. I basically just need the variables in order to print them in a more formatted way.

Comment: If you can't use lists, just have a `private Course[] courses` field in your Student class, and a `setCourse(Course[] courses)` to assign the courses to your student (or an additional `Course[]` argument to your Student constructor).

Comment: You'll like lists and maps.  You can still use the technique above even with arrays even if it isn't quite as elegant.  The point is if you tie classes to students you organizational pain will go away.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. I've made a Course[] inside of Student. Is there a way to set two Course[] equal to each other? Or should I just be adding the courses individually to the one inside of Student where I was previously adding them into the new Course[] object?

Comment: Leave your code as is, and after the for loop which fills the courses array, call `student.setCourses(courses);`. As simple as that.

Comment: I have edited the code and tried to implement your solution, but now am getting a NullPointerException when trying to call upon an index of the Students array in a different class. Did I screw up somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The natural object mapping for your file would be a list of `Student` objects, each containing a list of `Course` objects. The `courses` array should be stored inside the student object.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but i could be because your answer is off topic and unrelated to the question asked, and makes assumptions about the assignment/structure of the file that are unfounded. It is perfectly reasonable to have a file with a list of students then a list of courses, with no implict object mapping or a file reading function which choses to ignore that mapping.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the file and the code used to read it? Each student line contains a number of courses, and the following lines are the courses of this student (one line per course). It's far from being off-topic: since this is how the data is structured, this is how the objects should be designed. And returning the list of students would return everything: the students, and their courses. There **IS** a relationship.

Comment: The sample file given clearly shows the intent is to tie courses to students.

Comment: We dont know the assingment however and shouldnt make assumptions. Perhapes this is an 'easy first assignment', which will later lead to more proper object mapping later in the course... The fact remains that the JBNizet was answering a question different then what was asked. edit: and like i said, i didnt downvote, and wouldn't, but i was just giving a possible reason.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, the way I would do this is have a data structure that represents the parsed file in memory.  So basically it would look something like this:

```
public class RegistrationFile{

  private Students[] students;
  private Courses[] courses;

  public void loadFromFile(File f){
  //do your logic to parse the file
  //and store the results in the appropriate data members
  }

  public Students[] getStudents(){
    return students;
  }

  public Courses[] getCourses(){
    return courses;
  }
}
```

From your other code, you would then create an instance of a registration file object and call `loadFromFile()` to load data before you attempt to access anything.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting up the right objects to represent students/courses (as @ChrisThompson has), you'll want to be able to read in any number of records for student/courses right?

You'll want to parse the file accordingly. For example when you hit a blank line you know you're moving on to the next record (except for first record). Also take advantage of the fact that the first line will be the student (or if it has 5 tokens) and the subsequent lines are her courses (or if the line has 4 tokens).

This unit should comprise one iteration in the loop over the entire input file. Create a given student object and his course objects one iteration of the loop.